# Mycurrent location latLng can not work on using cordova cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I tried to find mycurrent location from android using with cordova cordova-plugin-googlemaps , but not running. whether latLng should be defined in advance as a variable ?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
          var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

          var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv);

          map.on(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapInit);
        });

        function onMapInit(map) {
            map:clear;
            var success = function(location) {
                map.addMarker({
                  'position': location.latLng,
                  'draggable': true
            },function(marker) {
                marker.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MARKER_DRAG_END, function(marker) {
                marker.getPosition(function(latLng) {
                marker.setTitle(latLng.toUrlValue());
                marker.showInfoWindow();    
                    });
                });
              map.animateCamera({
                'target':location.latLng,
                'zoom':18  
              },function(){
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                }); 
              });
          };

          var error = function(result){
            alert ("ERROR\n---\n" + result.error_message);
          };
          map.getMyLocation(success, error);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I would start by making sure the application asks for permissions to access the user's location, I would also recommend you to use the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation to fetch the users position.

Comment: Thanks @valarauko, i try add plugin geolocation, and result same cannot run

Comment: In the cordova documentation there is an example of what you are trying to do using the geolocation plugin, you can check here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html#see-where-you-are-on-a-map. Also, remember to add the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to your android manifest. I would recommend you that you first try check that you are actually getting the device location and then try to include the map marker set position. Would you mind to edit your question with the geolocation approach?

Comment: SOLVED my problem just delete `map:clear;` it's run current location, thanks all..